# How to use different Web.config value by different configuration dynamically and use Base.config (.NET Framework)

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config, .net-framework-version, .net-4.8

I want to use different Web.config when program run in different configuration (Debug Release)
I add Web.Debug.config,Web.Release.config and Web.Base.config by myself

When value doesn't set,use Web.Base.config

Web.Base.config set Timeout value => `<add key="Timeout" value="30"/>`
Web.Debug.config doesn't set Timeout value
Web.Release.config set Timeout value => `<add key="Timeout" value="60"/>`

I want
run in Debug configuration,Timeout is 30 (from Web.Base.config)
run in Release configuration,Timeout is 60 (from Web.Release.config)

How to do this in .NET Framework(4.6.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add `<add key="IsDebug" value=0 or 1>`, and then use `<add key="TimeOutRelease">`,`<add key="TimeOutDebug">` and any others.

Comment: Actually I have 4 configuration,Debug,UAT,PreProd and  Prod
I just make it simple to descript

Comment: @Jake I think this article would help you :[link](https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/Blog/Skyline-Blog/October-2011/Managing-Web-Config-Settings-For-Multiple-Environm)